# How to add focus event to template

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm trying to add autocomplete functionality to the search box in my home page and I want `onfocus` event for template to pass this jQuery command source elements. I added jQuery to my meteor app like this `mrt add jquery-ui-bootstrap`

```
Template.index.events({
    'focus input.focus-eve':function() {
        $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

```
<input id="autocomplete" class="focus-eve" name="search-txt-box" type="text"  size="80"  placeholder="Search..." />
```

It is still not working. I added both jQuery and jQuery-UI to my app.

**UPDATE**

I added the `jquery-ui-bootstrap` package not the `jquery-ui` package.

The problem is now solved. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event is targeting an `input` element with class `focus-eve`, but your `input` in the HTML does not have a class attribute. Try changing your event to `'focus input'` or just `'focus'`.

Comment: i changed my code to this   'Template.index.events({
 'focus':function()
 {
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
  });
 }

 });' still not working